# SharePoint Search Usage Logs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-search

The out-of-the-box SharePoint usage logs are a great way to get insights on what are most frequently searched terms, queries returning no results, etc. Is there a way I can get these stats by users too. I mean, what has each user tried to search when and whether s/he got the results or not? If not OOTB, does any third party tool assists in getting these stats?

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that ootb (without developing on the server)

SharePoint doesn't expose this data.

you can check CardioLog - great tool but require deep understanding...

if they search from a single page you can put a script that saves every query to a different DB.